# Gate Driver keeps burning

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, bootstrap

I'm designing an MPPT charger with a Synchronous Boost Converter using the LTC4444 gate driver. For prototyping I made a 1 layer pcb where I soldered all the components and added a few cables. The first time I tested the circuit with Vin = 5V and it was working correctly, I tried it the next day and it was no longer working.

I supply the gate driver with 12V using a DC Power Supply which works fine without applying any PWM signal. After I activate the PWM the voltage drops to around 6.5V and the current rises to the limit of current I used 0.04A. If I raise the current the voltage is able to reach the 12V, but the gate driver doesn't work. This led me to conclude the gate driver had burned.

**I FORGOT TO REFER BEFORE:** If I only apply a PWM signal on the low side, the gate driver works correctly, applying any voltage in the high side input will make the supply voltage drop and the supply current rise. This means that the high side is the one getting damaged, without affecting the load side.

I soldered a new gate driver and tested it again without any load. At first the gate driver signals were okay, but after a few seconds the voltage at Vcc droped and the current rised, just like before. This happended 3 times. I've tried checking all the wires and paths on the PCB and everything seems ok, I don't know why this is happening, but I suspect there must be a mistake on the bootstrapping of the gate driver.

The PWM signal comes directly from the uC, a Teensy 3.2, and it has a frequency of 80kHz. I then invert the signal using a NAND IC, the SN74S00N.
[image]

I also send some pictures of the PCB, the Gate driver has already been removed 3 times, so the PCB is already a bit damaged from the heat but the paths and cables are working correctly:

[image]

[image]

Links of the datasheets for [Gate Driver](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC4444.pdf), [MOSFETs](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSC070N10NS5-DataSheet-v02_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a0bf290014a0fc62d9d6b3c), [bootstrap diode](https://pt.mouser.com/datasheet/2/395/TSSW3U45%20SERIES_A1606-1125732.pdf) & [bootstrap capacitor](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/885012209069.pdf).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Scope your gate-source voltages. Add series gate resistors to dampen ringing. I think you may need more than one layer for a ground plane. Too much parasitic inductance.

Comment: Did you test a brand new driver with the supply on 40 mA current limit?

Comment: I think it might be helpful to observe some of the nodes with an oscilloscope to see what is going on. Usually each mosfet has a gate resistor (in series with the gate). Also, I see that you have deliberately elongated the top gate trace, which seems odd. Not necessarily the cause of your problem, but could contribute.

Comment: If you shorted gate to source on the synchronous MOSFET (and disconnected the gate from the driver and bootstrap circuit) it will just operate as a regular boost - does this still destroy the driver?

Comment: Add some load at the output. You cannot apply PWM without feedback and without any load.

Comment: @fifi_22 Huh, where is the feedback? Good point.

Comment: It’s a synchronous boost and will operate in CCM irrespective of load, hence the output voltage will remain roughly in regulation under a vast array of load conditions.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes I din't think before of adding the gate resistors, but for the next iteration i will use a multylayer pcb to include them and also the ground plane.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I tested with the 40mA current limit. I haven't tried shorting the top MOSFET to use it a as diode. I forgot to refer that when the gate driver stops working, this only happens when I connect the high side, if I send a PWM signal only through the bottom side, the bottom side output works correctly and the driver accepts the 12V without any current rising. So given this, using the MOSFET as diode should work i guess.

Comment: @mkeith The reason I elongated the top gate trace is because i read the two traces should have a similar length, and since the bottom trace was almost 5 times longer I tried to balance them

Comment: @fifi_22 The feedback signal will go directly to the microcontroller. Right now im not changing the pwm signal, its constant.

Comment: @LuisNovoa it will work but now it won't regulate on light loads without strong intervention from PWM duty cycle. As you previously had it you can rely on back feeding energy from the output capacitor to store energy in the inductor and save input energy when operating on light loads but now, for it to work across a low to high load range you need feedback to set the PWM duty.

Comment: To those looking for feedback: maybe there is some confusion here. MPPTs use feedback to set the input impedance of the DC/DC converter to Rmpp to optimise Pout of the solar panel; they don't (try to) regulate output and don't do or need Vout feedback.

Comment: The driver is failing because of some overvoltage probably. I would suggest probing the various nodes carefully to look for anomolies. If there is some way to get the circuit to not blow up immediately, that might allow you enough time probing to figure it out. Maybe start by using a lower voltage if you can. Look for overshoot at the bootstrap node and the two gate and source nodes to see if they are going over the maximum ratings. Also, you may want to slowly ramp up the duty cycle rather than apply it all at once (to reduce ringing and overshoot on the output filter).

Comment: I am assuming you have an oscilloscope. If not, it will be more difficult.

Comment: You cannot operate without load or feedback, becauose overvoltage will happen